# mpdf can't show background colour on an entire column on a table

Tags: html-table, colors, mpdf

I'm trying to set a background color on a full column on a table using a col tag with a style option but it's not working. I can see my table but no colors.

I'tried also using a col class set by css and it's not working too.

```
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<table>');
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<colgroup>');
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<col span="2" style="background-color:#FAF0C2;"');
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<col span="2" style="background-color:#E3DEE4;"');
$mpdf->WriteHTML('</colgroup>');
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<tr>');
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<td>1</td>');
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<td>2</td>');
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<td>3</td>');
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<td>4</td>');
$mpdf->WriteHTML('</tr>');
$mpdf->WriteHTML('</table>');
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code is, you didn't close the col tag. Use the below code and see if this works.

```
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<table>');
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<colgroup>');
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<col span="2" style="background-color:#FAF0C2;">');
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<col span="2" style="background-color:#E3DEE4;">');
$mpdf->WriteHTML('</colgroup>');
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<tr>');
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<td>1</td>');
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<td>2</td>');
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<td>3</td>');
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<td>4</td>');
$mpdf->WriteHTML('</tr>');
$mpdf->WriteHTML('</table>');
```

Comment: I am doubtful about CSS support for COL tag working on mPDF.
As per this link(https://mpdf.github.io/html-support/html-tags.html), mPDF supports COL tag. But here, They havent mentioned any CSS support for COL tag (https://mpdf.github.io/css-stylesheets/supported-css.html). Try using some other formating instead of <COl>

Comment: I want to set a background color for a full column on a big table.... so I don't know how to do it in a different way

Comment: If that's the case, then you should try adding CSS for alternative <td> elements and adjust the spacing

Comment: It's not possible because in some lines the background color's changing will be in the middle of a td (colspan)

Comment: Then you should look for alternatives. Maybe you can remove the table and use DIVs to make it look like table with desired css.

Comment: As per your code, you have 4 <td> elements in which first 2<td> have a background color and next 2 <td> have a background color.
So the below code should work as you want right?
<tr>
<td style="background-color:#FAF0C2;">1</td>
<td style="background-color:#FAF0C2;">2</td>
<td style="background-color:#E3DEE4;">3</td>
<td style="background-color:#E3DEE4;">4</td>
</tr>

Comment: it's a simplified table... my real one is huge. 
I told you I know how to do it but it's not compatible with my full table because of colspans. 
My question is : how can I modifiy background color for a full column in a table generated by mpdf